# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, sql, select, resultset

Allright been trying to figure this out the last 2 days.

```
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                        String query = "SELECT * FROM sell";
                        ResultSet rs = query(query);
                        while (rs.next()){//<--- I get there operation error here
```

This is the query method.

```
    public static ResultSet query(String s) throws SQLException {
        try {
            if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith("select")) {
                if(stm == null) {
                    createConnection();
                }
                ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(s);
                return rs;
            } else {
                if(stm == null) {
                    createConnection();
                }
                stm.executeUpdate(s);
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            con = null;
            stm = null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are there any other threads in your application?

Comment: It would be useful if you post the actual error you're getting.  People can't really help with issues without a description of what's happening.  I also don't ever see where in the "query" method you are creating the connection or statement.  I see a call to createConnection(), but no assignment there, and no assignment of "stm" inside that method.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to be sure just from the code you've posted, but I suspect that the `ResultSet` is inadvertently getting closed (or `stm` is getting reused) **inside the body of the `while` loop**. This would trigger the exception at the start of the following iteration.

Additionally, you need to make sure there are no other threads in your application that could potentially be using the same DB connection or `stm` object.

Comment: it' worth. Code is dirty written and unnecessarily complicated written.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, you should do everything you need with your ResultSet before you close your connection.

Answer (score 2):

there are few things you need to fix. Opening a connection, running a query to get the rs, closing it, and closing the connection all should be done in the same function scope as far as possible. from your code, you seem to use the "con" variable as a global variable, which could potentially cause a problem. you are not closing the stm object. or the rs object. this code does not run for too long, even if it has no errors. Your code should be like this:

```
if (stringUtils.isBlank(sql)){
     throw new IllegalArgumentsException ("SQL statement is required");
}
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps =null;
Resultset rs = null;
try{
         con = getConnection();
         ps = con.preparestatement(sql);
         rs = ps.executeQuery();
         processResults(rs);
         close(rs);
         close(ps);
         close(con);
}catch (Execption e){
        log.Exception ("Error in: {}", sql, e);
        throw new RuntimeException (e);
}finally{
        close(rs);
        close(ps);
        close(con);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use another Statement object in inner loop
Like

```
Statement st,st1;

st=con.createStatement();
st1=con.createStatement();

//in Inner loop
while(<<your code>>)
{
   st1.executeQuery(<<your query>>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few years late, but I've found that synchronizing the db methods usually get rid of this problem.